# Unable to force program termination in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exit

I wrote a program that calls another program from itself through the `subprocess` library and then terminates itself through `sys.exit()`.

But it's not that simple. There should be a list of questions. (note, it will not be about the script itself, but about the application of this script created through pyinstaller)

1. When I go to the task manager, in the details tab, I see there 4 test.exe, 2 of them are running in the current folder, the other 2 are in `APPDATA\Local\test`
2. `os.remove(o)` is not executed
3. `path + f'\\{k}.txt'` saves only in `APPDATA\Local\test`, and `f'{k}test.txt'` only to current folder

Apparently, the program does not start from appdata at all, but it is not so, because in the task manager it is shown, even twice. What is the reason for this behavior? And how to fix it?

UPD: I have ensured that files are saved only in upadte, writing `os.chdir(path)` after `else:`. But first execution still cannot complete.

```
import sys
import os
import time


path = os.path.dirname(os.getenv('APPDATA')) + '\\Local\\test'
try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except OSError:
    pass
if not os.path.isfile(path + '\\test.exe'):
    with open(path + '\\info.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(sys.argv[0])
    subprocess.call(['copy', sys.argv[0], path + '\\test.exe'], shell=True)
    subprocess.call(path + '\\test.exe', shell=True)
    sys.exit()
else:
    with open(path + '\\info.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        o = f.readline()
        if os.path.isfile(o):
            try:
                os.remove(o)
            except:
                pass

k = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    with open(path + f'\\{k}.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write('test message 1')
    with open(f'{k}test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write('test message 2')
    k += 1
```

Comment: Are the contents of info.txt absolute paths?

Comment: Yes, `sys.argv[0]` returns the absolute path when we launch the app by clicking on the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem kill the process via taskkill. As a result, the code after `else` looks like this:

```
os.chdir(path)
with open(path + '\\info.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    o = f.readline()
    if os.path.isfile(o):
        subprocess.call(['TASKKILL', '/IM', 'test.exe', '/F'], shell=True)
        os.remove(o)
```

In doing so, I made the names of the two programs different in order to properly kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are asking many questions that don't relevant to each other. Second I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here but I'm going to give you a brief answer for each.

1. The apps created with PyInstaller (with -F flag) deploys two processes. One for extracting contents of the executable and clean up after the code executed and second of is your program itself. And additionally, you are calling the executable with `subprocess` so it would become 4 processes.
2. After creating your executable, the `sys.argv[0]` would be equal to the path of the executable itself. Thus you can't call the `os.remove()` to delete the executable itself.
3. I'm not sure about the question but `os.path.dirname(os.getenv('APPDATA'))` would be translated to the user's AppData path, but `f'{k}test.txt'` would be translated to the current executable path where executable is located.

Comment: At first... You say that 4 processes are created. OK. However, I terminate one of the two programs via sys.exit(). Why then do I still have 4 processes left?

Comment: It is getting weird because you are going to execute `test.exe` in a nested way, your script is going to call itself over and over, no matter if you call `sys.exit`. I still can't get what are you trying to do here.

Comment: I want the executable to run in the current folder, create and run its copy in the AppData and terminate itself via sys.exit(). Then the copy deletes this helper executable and starts creating files with test messages in the AppData (in the current folder relative to itself). Are you saying that a program does not terminate because another program was started from it? Then what do I need to change in the code to make it work as I described above?

Comment: The problem is how are you gonna tell the copy to delete the first process that launches it? You need to check whether the executable is running from the desired path or not if yes then make a decision. Then you can safely exit your code.

Comment: That is, you offer instead of `not os.path.isfile(path + '\\test.exe')` to put the `not sys.argv[0] == path + 'test.exe'`? Are you sure this will work?

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is that, as you said, `After creating your executable, the sys.argv[0] would be equal to the path of the executable itself`. Well. Then I have such a question, how to call a copy so that it does not inherit the path from where it is called. Can need to hand its this path in arguments or still something? Could you introduce the code?

Comment: I solved the path inheritance problem (see question) and realized that the first program after `sys.exit()` really stops working. And now I have only 1 question left: why does the program continue to run and the process does not end?!